# How to convert this curl command to libcurl

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I succeed to login www.tistory.com by using curl command like this.

```
curl -c cookie.txt -d "loginId=xxx&password=xxx&form_id=authForm" https://www.tistory.com/auth/login
```

And... to use it on my c++ project, I converted it to libcurl like this.

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
char *location;
long response_code;

curl = curl_easy_init();

if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.tistory.com/auth/login");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");

    const char* postData = "loginId=xxx&password=xxx&form_id=authForm";

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postData);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, strlen(postData));

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    ......
}

......
```

This converted code doesn't work. And cookie.txt file wasn't saved, too. I don't know where is wrong or what I missed. Somebody let me know. Thanks in advance.

Here is result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQnSz.png)

Comment: C or C++? They are two very different languages, so please pick one. And *how* doesn't the code work? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Note that you have `cookies.txt` not `cookie.txt`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I picked c++ and added result image to show response code and edited typo.

Comment: It would appear the only difference is the lack of a `User-Agent:` header in your libcurl case... (and please don't use an image to show text response)

Comment: @DanielStenberg You are right. I inserted this code `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.61.0");` and it works fine. Thank you very much! And I will remember your advice about text response. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to convert a curl command line to C code is to use the `--libcurl code.c` command line option.

When doing that and comparing the output with your code snippet, it would appear the only difference between the two programs is the lack of a `User-Agent:` header in your libcurl-using program.

Comment: i was looking for a way to convert curl to libcurl and didn't think of --libcurl  option, thanks

Comment: Works like charm! BTW I have tried manual conversion, postman and some other online converts. All failed.